# Determine when heading off course

Tags: gps, algorithm, routing, openlayers

How does google or other map providers with routing capabilities determine when you are not staying at the right course?
I am trying to figure out how to implement this feature in my gps that I am developing.
Right now I have the polyline with all the coordinates and the location of the device. Is there any general algorithm I can use?

Comment: Which techniques/mapping libraries do you use?

Comment: Im using openlayers-3. I generate my own polylines and draw them on the map where I also have my current position shown

Comment: It's quite an interesting question. I have no idea what Google use internally, but I'm guessing some kind of stack or queue to keep the route and [distance from point to line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) calculations, using only the route segments at the front of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenLayers 2 I just used a method of the OpenLayers-feature to check wether it is within a geofencing-zone.I haven't tried this with ol3. Another option would be turf: 
https://www.mapbox.com/blog/turf-gis-for-web-maps/
See the section"Water Fountains accessible within xxx feet". Instead of water fountains you could use your gps-position with a buffer around your track. (But probably turf won't work in combination with ol3)
Concerning ol3 see https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/ol3-dev/1GlkigfBLx4/9wsXShe_SlUJ